# How to simplify a sum of a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T$ be any square $m \times m$ matrix, $U$ be a $v \times m$ matrix, and define $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n T^k$. By geometric matrix series, I know the that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n UT^k = U\sum_{k=0}^n T^k = US_n = U(1-T)^{-1}(I-T^{n+1})$$
assuming that $I-T$ is invertible.

Now suppose I have $m \times m$ matrices $T_0, T_1, \ldots$ and $v \times m$ matrices $U_1, U_2, \ldots$ and I have the finite sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left\{ U_k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} T_j\right\}$$

Is there a way to write the above sum without the summation like I did with $\sum_{k=0}^n UT^k$ above? Clearly, I think the geometric matrix series property does not apply here. But I'm wondering if there is another property that I can use here?

Comment: Hint: if what you're asking is possible, it must generalize the case $m=v=1$.

Comment: I see. Should I try it for scalars first and see if I can drop the summation somehow? Or are you implying that what I'm asking is not possible?

Comment: I assume $T_k$ meant $T_j$, but even if all $T$s were the same you'd be considering an arbitrary polynomial in one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, the special case $m=v=1,\,T_j=T$ makes $\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{U_k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}T_j\right\}$ an arbitrary degree-$n$ polynomial in $T$ vanishing at $T=0$. Such a general family of polynomials admits no nicer form than that.